# What Japanese word is used as a classification for all profanities?

Tags: colloquial-language

What is a classification word for all profanities and obscenities?
Does Japanese have a euphemism similar to "f-word" in English?  Does 悪口 fit the definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「放送禁止用語{ほうそうきんしようご}」 would be a fairly safe word choice here.  Literally, that means "the words forbidden on the air".  Though it uses six kanji, it is not a heavy-sounding word at all.

If you used a more "dictionary translation" kind of word such as 「卑語{ひご}」 or 「冒涜的{ぼうとくてき}な言葉{ことば}」, it would be much more uncommon and it would sound much heavier and technical.

「悪口{わるぐち}」 means a totally different thing.  It means "abuse", "slander", etc.  It refers to the action and not the words uttered themselves.